# How to force close terminal window id using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, osascript

I am starting a new terminal window from a terminal:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "myProgram.sh"'`

Since the new process is not ending(it is basically a server), I want to be able to stop it  at some point using AppleScript.

If I do:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to close window id {windowId}'`

I am getting the alert box `"Do you want to terminate running process...?"`.

Is it possible to force close the window id? If not, how can I confirm this alert box using AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use osascript to use the dialog and press Terminate:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to close first window' \
          -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"' \
            -e 'tell window 1' \
              -e 'tell sheet 1' \
                -e 'click button "Terminate"' \
              -e 'end tell' \
            -e 'end tell' \
          -e 'end tell'
```

Working for me, stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103658/9259703.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
do shell script "killall -QUIT Terminal"
```

I hope this helps you solve your problem .