# how to keep angular universal server running after closing the terminal

Tags: angular, vpn, angular-universal

I have an angular app running with angular universal
I have a VPN hosting and log in with the mac terminal (ssh root@ip_address)

when I log in and run

```
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

Everything work well... Until I close the terminal which somehow kill the VPN server... How can I log out of ssh without killing the server?

Edit :
I have a VPN thus running a remote linux terminal. When I run pm2, even when I log out of my SSH, the server remain online, but for universal, it does not, it looks like logging out of SSH kill the process.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243553/running-process-in-background-after-closing-terminal   It has several suggestions including running it in the background and using screen.

Comment: What about `npm run build:ssr && bash -c "nohup npm run serve:ssr &"` (based on the answer to the question I already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure it’s always running - and restarts if it ever stops - then you’ll want a more “production ready” answer.

But I suspect you’re looking for a quick and dirty solution.

Run this inside a “screen session”. When you login over ssh type `screen` to start a screen session. This session will continue to run even when you end or disconnect your ssh session.

Once you’ve started the screen session with that simple command; just run your npm command and it’ll keep running until you tell it to stop (or it crashes)

See https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/keep-processes-running-ssh-logout-linux/ for a bit more about screen.

Comment: How do I start a screen session? I just logged on my ssh, but then?  what strange is that with pm2, it is all perfect but with angular universal, for some reason it does not

Comment: Thanks @Tom Harvey, but I got "command not found" when I type it

Comment: So you have to install it. `apt-get install screen` on Ubuntu. Or `yum install screen` for a centos server. What OS does your server run?